# NFC Tag & MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, nfc

First of all, apologies for the lack of code within this question. It's purely for information to further develop my project.

I'm after using nfc tag technology with mobile phones, what I want to achieve is on scanning of an nfc tag, my local or cloud server is updated with the ID and time/date of scan.

I've looked on various forums, done countless searches on the web but for some reason cannot find a clear point to start from.

I'm comfortable with all web languages however I just can't get my head around the process, do you scan a given nfc tag which then loads a url with the ID of the tag in a get method.

Or is there something I can do within an app which will update the server on scan.

Again apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to store a URL in the NFC tag which points to your server application. You can add an ID to the URL, which identifies the tag towards the server. The timestamp can come from the server, when he receives the HTTP Request. Your server application can then store the ID together with the time.

This approach will not need any specific app on the mobile, any NFC capable phone will do that out of the box.

Should you need a local timestamp from the mobile phone, then will need an NFC app which takes the NFC intent, formes the proper URL including the locally generated data and send that off to your server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @corvairjo - Just a quick question, on scanning the tag will this then open a browser on the device? i'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: When you store a URL on the tag, then the phone will open the browser together with the URL.  Depending oon the nature of your application, you can use the browser to give the user a feedback about his action.  When you do not want the browser visible, that you need to do your own app.